# GroupBy linq works only on adjacent records

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a problem using groupby operator in linq. I am using .Net Core EF, so I am not really sure whether there is a bug on it, or if I am doing something wrong. I am trying to perform a grouping on a table which contains several records. My grouping key is a non-anonymous entity that gets its values from navigating a level down the db structure.
In the following example, I am interested in grouping records present on the ResultTable, by the values given by the `TypeId` and `OtherId` properties.

```
ResultTable
- ResultId
- DetailId (FK)

DetailTable
- DetailId
- TypeId (maps to enum, not null)
- OtherId (FK, null)
```

My code to group is the following:

```
private IQueryable<IGrouping<Grouper, Result>> GetGroupedResults()
{
    var results = MyContext.ResultSet.Include(r => r.Detail);
    var groupedResults = results.GroupBy(r => new Grouper(r.Detail.TypeId, r.Detail.OtherId ?? 0));
    return groupedResults ;
}
```

The definition of my grouper entity is as follows:

```
public class Grouper
{
    public Grouper(Type type, int otherId)
    {
        Type= type;
        OtherId = otherId;
    }
    public Type Type{ get; } // this is an enum
    public int OtherId  { get; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var p = obj as Grouper;
        if (p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return (Type == p.Type ) && (OtherId  == p.OtherId);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (int)Type ;
    }
}
```

What I would expect this to do is the following. Lets say that I have the following records:

```
ResultTable
ResultId: 1, DetailId: 1
ResultId: 2, DetailId: 2
ResultId: 3, DetailId: 3
ResultId: 4, DetailId: 4

DetailTable
DetailId: 1, TypeId: 1, OtherId: 1
DetailId: 2, TypeId: 1, OtherId: 1
DetailId: 3, TypeId: 2, OtherId: NULL
DetailId: 4, TypeId: 1, OtherId: 1
```

Considering that data I would expect two groups with the following keys and values

1. First group with key Grouper(Type: 1, OtherId: 1), values ResultId(1, 2, 4)
2. Second group with key Grouper(Type: 2, OtherId: 0), values ResultId(3)

However I am not getting this. I am instead getting three groups with keys and values as follows:

1. First group with key Grouper(Type: 1, OtherId: 1), values ResultId(1, 2, 4)
2. Second group with key Grouper(Type: 2, OtherId: 0), values ResultId(3)
3. Third group with key Grouper(Type: 1, OtherId: 1), values ResultId(4)

It seems as if the GroupBy operation were only capable of grouping records with subsequent id's. Why is this happening?
Greetings
Luis.

**EDIT:** Using an anonymous type to perform grouping results in correct groups, could it be the way I am defining my Grouper class?

Comment: When setting this up to test in visual studio, I noticed that you're passing a `Type` to your `Grouper`.  your description of your schema makes it sound `Type` is an `enum` you've defined, but `Type` already exists in the `System` namespace, and it's one of the more fundamental classes in c#

Comment: Additionally, the code you've posted will throw a `NotSupportedException` becaues `Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities`.  It appears as though using a parameterized constructor for Grouper is not allowed.  I suspicion is that you've did something to `results` that executed the query such as `results.ToList()`

Comment: You've posted a lot of information, but I would recommend that you make an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that people can literally copy and paste to experience your issue for themselves

Comment: and don't call me "Luis"